# vue.js deployment pointing to wrong static assets directory

Tags: vue.js, npm

I am trying to deploy my first application made with vue-cli,

everything works in npm run dev, 
now when I build with npm run build, it created dist directory, with file structure:
index.html
static/

but every reference in index.html etc.. is to /app/static

```
src=/app/static/js/vendor.87e3cb
```

if I create a directory named app and copy static to /app than everything works.

I am obviously missing something simple.

Answer (score 1):

simple enough, in /config/index.js file, I had assetsPublicPath: '/app/',
set only for build, but commented out for dev.